# Why does compareTo not compare these Character values?

Tags: java, insertion-sort, compareto

I'm trying to implement an insertion sort in Java, to fully understand it before implementing Timsort. I'm using generic ArrayLists to handle the lists. My implementation seems to work with any set of Integer objects, however when I used Character objects the compareTo() part failed to compare them? I used a similar comparison in another sorting algorithm with no Character problems. Cannot think of what could cause this.

Here is the sorting algorithm:

```
public static <T extends Comparable> ArrayList<T> InsertionSort(ArrayList<T> inputArray) {

    for (int i = 1; i < inputArray.size(); i++) {
        T temp = inputArray.get(i);
        int j = i - 1;

        while (j >= 0 && inputArray.get(j).compareTo(temp) == 1) {
            inputArray.set(j + 1, inputArray.get(j));
            j--;
        }

        inputArray.set(j + 1, temp);
    }

    return inputArray;
}
```

and for input `[5, 7, 2, 78, 4, 8, 89, 32, 9, 45, 67, 66, 72, 100, 99, 3]` I get `[2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 32, 45, 66, 67, 72, 78, 89, 99, 100]`

but for input `[f, r, e, b, i, y, d, t, m]` I get `[f, r, e, b, i, y, d, t, m]`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't use `== 1` but `>= 1` or `> 0`. `compareTo()` doesn't have to return -1, 0 and 1 but negative integers, 0 or positive integers. That also explains why your code works with integers but not with characters: `Integer.compareTo()` returns -1 or 1 but `Character.compareTo()` returns `x - y`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problem:

```java
inputArray.get(j).compareTo(temp) == 1
```

You're assuming that `Comparable.compareTo` will return exactly 1 if the first argument is "greater than" the second argument. Instead, the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) only talks about the *sign* of the result:

> Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

So your check should be `> 0` rather than `== 1`.